# What is the idiomatic way to write a for loop without using the iterator value?

Tags: rust

Assuming I want a finite loop using a range:

```
let mut x: i32 = 0;
for i in 1..10 {
    x += 1;
}
```

The compiler will spit out the warning:

```
warning: unused variable: `i`, #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
for i in 1..10 {
    ^
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to write this that won't make the compiler complain?

Comment: Note that **`1..10` only yields from 1 to 9**. **It does *not* yield `10`**, in case that is what you are expecting. Therefore your code only executes 9 times. To include 10, you should get `1..=10`, but if you want more idiomatic Rust code, we usually write `0..10` (which is more relatable if you later want to use `i` as an array index later on).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can write `_` as your pattern, meaning “discard the value”:

```
let mut x: i32 = 0;
for _ in 1..10 {
    x += 1;
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  I have been hunting for an hour for this answer and you plainly & clearly answered it! Many thanks! +1