# How to loop certain (variable) number of times?

Tags: for-loop, rust, iterator, integer

This question may seem extremely basic, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this. I have an integer, and I need to use a for loop to loop integer number of times.

First, I tried -

```
fn main() {
    let number = 10; // Any value is ok
    for num in number {
        println!("success");
    }
}
```

this prints the error

```
error[E0277]: `{integer}` is not an iterator
 --> src/main.rs:3:16
  |
3 |     for num in number{
  |                ^^^^^^ `{integer}` is not an iterator
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `{integer}`
  = note: if you want to iterate between `start` until a value `end`, use the exclusive range syntax `start..end` or the inclusive range syntax `start..=end`
  = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

Next, I tried -

```
fn main() {
    let number = 10; // Any value is ok
    for num in number.iter() {
        println!("success");
    }
}
```

the compiler says there is no method iter for integer

```
error[E0599]: no method named `iter` found for type `{integer}` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:23
  |
3 |     for num in number.iter() {
  |                       ^^^^
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make a range in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271970/how-do-you-make-a-range-in-rust)

Comment: Also worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27893223/

Comment: Also relevant: [What is the idiomatic way to write a for loop without using the iterator value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932503/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-write-a-for-loop-without-using-the-iterator-value).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you are saying to the compiler for a `num` contained in `number` where `number` is not an iterator and neither does implement [iter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/), rather than for a `num` in the [range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.Range.html) `0..number` which is an iterator.

The documentation describes the `for` loop as:

```rust
for loop_variable in iterator {
    code()
}
```

Change the code to:

```rust
fn main() {
    let number = 10; 
    for num in 0..number { // change it to get range
        println!("success");
    }
}
```

You can also change it to:

```rust
fn main() {
    let number = 10; 
    for num in 1..=number { // inclusive range
        println!("success");
    }
}
```

Or to:

```rust
fn main() {
    let number = 10; 
    for _ in 0..number { // where _ is a "throw away" variable
        println!("success");
    }
}
```

Also see [for documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/keyword.for.html)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share this closure-based groovy-inspired way of looping n times in Rust.

```
pub trait Times {
    fn times(&self, f:fn(Self));
}

impl Times for u8 {
    fn times(&self, f:fn(u8)) {
        for x in 0..*self {
            f(x)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    const K: u8 =7;
    4.times( |v:u8| { println!("Inline Closure {v}.{K}"); } );
}
```

The output is:

```
Inline Closure 0.7
Inline Closure 1.7
Inline Closure 2.7
Inline Closure 3.7
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it!

Comment: That is beautiful code. Of course, Groovy was inspired by Ruby with that syntax!

Answer (score 2):

Rust for-loops take an iterator (actually anything that can be [converted into an iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html)). An sole integer can not be converted into an iterator, but a [range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) can.

```rust
fn main() {
    let number = 10; // Any value is ok
    for num in 0..number {
        println!("success");
    }
}
```

https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=029803cf8ac6efaa3113b2f32ae6ef0d

Comment: How does your answer differ from the suggest duplicate? Please avoid adding redundant information. That's whats the duplicate flag is for. For more information see [help/duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: sorry, that i haven't seen the comment while i was typing this.